# Open graph - displaying multiple aggregations

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have an open graph application which, has the **Event** option, with 2 actions, **create** and **recommend**.  I also defined 2 aggregations: **Events I recommended** and **Events I created**.

However in the timeline, I can see only one of the aggregations, whichever is triggered first.

In the facebook examples it shows that it is possible to display both aggregation.  Is it possible to show both aggregations?

Answer (score 0):

You app page will have all the aggregations, but on main timeline you only get one aggregation.